# p-values of correlation coefficients

Tags: r, correlation

I am using R and have a question on correlations.

```
A<-data.frame(A1=c(1,2,3,4,5),B1=c(6,7,8,9,10),C1=c(11,12,13,14,15 ))
B<-data.frame(A2=c(6,7,7,10,11),B2=c(2,1,3,8,11),C2=c(1,5,16,7,8))
cor(A,B)
#           A2        B2       C2
# A1 0.9481224 0.9190183 0.459588
# B1 0.9481224 0.9190183 0.459588
# C1 0.9481224 0.9190183 0.459588
```

I wanted to obtain the p-value for each of the correlation coefficients in the matrix. Is this possible?

I tried using `rcorr` function from Hmisc package but obtain only a single p-value and not for each correlation.

```
A <- as.vector(t(A))
B <- as.vector(t(B))
rcorr(A, B)
     x    y
x 1.00 0.13
y 0.13 1.00

n= 15 


P
  x      y     
x        0.6425
y 0.6425
```

Similarly, I also tried using "psych" package in R to do this but unable to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `rcorr` directly on `A` and `B` if you convert them to matrices first :

```
library(Hmisc)
rcorr(as.matrix(A),as.matrix(B))
```

Which gives :

```
     A1   B1   C1   A2   B2   C2
A1 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.95 0.92 0.46
B1 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.95 0.92 0.46
C1 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.95 0.92 0.46
A2 0.95 0.95 0.95 1.00 0.97 0.16
B2 0.92 0.92 0.92 0.97 1.00 0.15
C2 0.46 0.46 0.46 0.16 0.15 1.00

n= 5 


P
   A1     B1     C1     A2     B2     C2    
A1        0.0000 0.0000 0.0141 0.0273 0.4361
B1 0.0000        0.0000 0.0141 0.0273 0.4361
C1 0.0000 0.0000        0.0141 0.0273 0.4361
A2 0.0141 0.0141 0.0141        0.0078 0.7981
B2 0.0273 0.0273 0.0273 0.0078        0.8125
C2 0.4361 0.4361 0.4361 0.7981 0.8125
```

Comment: @ juba: I have one more clarification on this data but its regarding permutations. Should I post it as a new question?

Comment: @user2810362 Is it a data manipulation question or a statistical one ? In the second case the question could  better go to Cross Validated.