# Correlation matrix with dplyr, tidyverse and broom - P-value matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation, tidyverse, broom

all. I want to obtain the p-value from a correlation matrix using **dplyr and/or broom packages** **and testing multiple variables at the same time**. I'm aware of other methods, but dplyr seems easier and more intuitive for me. In addition, dplyr will need to correlate each variable to obtain the specific p-value, what makes the process easier and faster.

I checked other links, but they did not work for this question ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461183/how-to-add-p-values-for-spearman-correlation-coefficients-plotted-using-pairs-in), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977750/p-values-of-correlation-coefficients), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435351/correlation-matrix-with-p-value-in-r)) 
When I use this code, the correlation coefficients are reported. However, the P-values are not.

```
agreg_base_tipo_a %>% 
  dplyr::select(S2.RT, BIS_total, IDATE, BAI, ASRS_total) %>% 
  do(as.data.frame(cor(., method="spearman", use="pairwise.complete.obs")))
```

Please, check out this reproducible code to word:

```
set.seed(1164)

library(tidyverse)
ds <- data.frame(id=(1) ,a=rnorm(10,2,1), b=rnorm(10,3,2), c=rnorm(5,1,05))

ds %>% 
  select(a,b,c) %>% 
  do(as.data.frame(cor(., method="spearman", use="pairwise.complete.obs")))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is based on akrun's comment from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50435351/7669809). By using the `rcorr` function, we can calculate the correlations and P values. To access these components, use `ds_cor$r` and `ds_cor$P`.

```
set.seed(1164)

library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)

ds <- data.frame(id=(1) ,a=rnorm(10,2,1), b=rnorm(10,3,2), c=rnorm(5,1,05))

ds_cor <- ds %>%
  select(-id) %>% 
  as.matrix() %>%
  rcorr(type = "spearman")

ds_cor
#    a     b     c
# a  1.00  0.28 -0.42
# b  0.28  1.00 -0.25
# c -0.42 -0.25  1.00
# 
# n= 10 
# 
# 
# P
#   a      b      c     
# a        0.4250 0.2287
# b 0.4250        0.4929
# c 0.2287 0.4929
```

Comment: Nice option with `rcorr`